# Добавлять в массив несколько переменных с помощью метода push

Tags: массивы, javascript

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты! У меня вопрос можно ли с помощью метода `push` добавлять в массив несколько переменных  вот пример:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    document.bgColor="khaki" 
    function f1(obj) {
        z=new Array()
        n=1*window.prompt("Введите количество чисел:");
        a1=1*window.prompt("Введите первое число:");
        min=a1;
        for (var i=1; i<n; i++) {
            a2=1*window.prompt("Введите следующее число:");
            v=z.push(a1,a2)
            obj.s4.value=v

            min=Math.min(a1, a2);
            obj.s3.value=min; 
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="myform">
    Минимальное <input type="Number" name="s3" size=5><hr>
    <input type=button name="b1"value="Запуск!" onclick="f1(myform)">
    <input type="Number" name="s4" size=10><hr>
```

Comment: Да, сколько угодно.

Comment: понятно, а вы не знает как сделать чтобы введеные числа добавлялись в массив, а потом из него в поля формы?

Comment: document.bgColor="khaki"  -- не делайте так НИКОГДА!!!

Comment: почему?А как задать цвет фона документу?

Comment: во-1, использовать значение цвета как #RRGGBB, а во вторых - даже для body нужно использовать style! видимо, у вас очень старый учебник по ЖС, попробуйте learn.javascript.ru

Answer (score 2):

Все добавляется. http://javascript.ru/Array/push

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
document.bgColor="khaki" ;
function f1(obj) { 
    z=new Array();
    var n=window.prompt("Введите количество чисел:");

    var a1=window.prompt("Введите первое число:");
    z.push(a1);
    var min=a1;
    for (var i=1; i<n; i++) { 
        a2=window.prompt("Введите следующее число:");
        z.push(a2);
        obj.s4.value=z.join();
        min=Math.min(min, a2);
        obj.s3.value=min;
    } 
    console.log(z);
} </script> 
<form name="myform"> Минимальное <input type="Number" name="s3" size=5><br> 
<input type=button name="b1" value="Запуск!" onclick="f1(myform)"> <br> 
Число элементов в массиве  z: <input name="s4" size=10><br>
```

В вашем примере у вас n=1 и условия обхода массива i = 1, i < n - он и не выполнится никогда.
Только не понял зачем вам выводить кол-во элементов в массиве.

Comment: вы наверно неправильно поняли мой вопрос он состоял в следующем: после того как пользователь вводил количество чисел,потом он набирал первое число,второе и так далее в зависимости от количества выбранных чисел,мне бы хотелось чтобы вот эти числа первое,второе,и так далее добавлялись в массив,а из него в поле формы в котором была бы последовательность этих чисел.

Comment: Заменить строки на:

var a1=window.prompt("Введите первое число:");
z.push(a1);
    var min=a1;
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) { 
        a2=window.prompt("Введите следующее число:");
        z.push(a2);
        obj.s4.value=z.join();

Comment: все равно в поле пишется не последовательность чисел, а число элементов в массиве

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PpLDZ/1/ не может быть...
Еще один нюанс - у вас 

<input type="Number" name="s4" size=10> 

нужно убрать type="Number", т.к. у вас будет строка из элементов массива, а не число.